# Need a simple solution for personal repository

Tags: sync, software-rec, repository

Not so much as a repository, but I don't know other better word. What I want to do is simple: To automatically sync a folder on my desktop to the repo, and when I want to resume my work on laptop, I can sync the repo to my laptop by one simple click, and whatever change I make on my laptop should be automatically synced to the repo so I can resume it on my desktop.

Google Drive doesn't work. Because with its desktop app, you can only sync from local to the Drive. It can only sync from Drive to local once, which is during the setup. After that, If you want to sync from file/folder from Drive, you need to manually download them. And the Drive has been acting up with its Zipping being frozen for a while - Sometimes I have to wait for 5 minutes while GD is zipping a folder composed of 4 less than 1k .js files.

Shall I tend to Bitbucket or Github for such simple functions? Or there is something out there that can achieve what I want to do? How about Onedrive and Dropbox, can they do what Google Drive fails to do?

Comment: Software/service recommendations are off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 0):

One Drive may be a good start. Someone correct me if I'm wrong. Go go File/Save As in any Microsoft Office program and you should see the option to save there.

Answer (score 0):

There's several you already notes OneDrive, there's Drop Box. But my favorite alternative is MEGA.NZ as it is 50GB FREE and there's not much hassles with the app.